# Scope, losing refernece to an object in a callback

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, scope

I'm extending a router in backbone -

```
Zoo.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    route: function (route, name, callback) {
      this._super(route, name, callback); //https://github.com/lukasolson/Backbone-Super
      var handler = Backbone.history.handlers[0]
      handler.callback = _(handler.callback).wrap(this._proxy_callback)
      return this
    },
    _proxy_callback: function(ev, foo){
      var args;
      args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
      this.trigger('before:route'); // Exception: Object #<Object> has no method 'trigger' 
      arguments[0].apply(this, args);
      return this.trigger('after:route');
    }
})
```

Once the proxy_callback is hit I'm unable to call this.trigger as I've lost reference to the object. How can I resolve this?

FYI - I'm attempting to rewrite a coffee script app in plain js. I'm not 100% certain on the 'whys' of this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're wrapping the `_proxy_callback` function in another function the scope changes to that function's context. You'll need to [`bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) `_proxy_callback` to the `Router`:

```
handler.callback = _(handler.callback).wrap(_.bind(this._proxy_callback, this));
```

That will keep the context where you want it. Bind ensures that `this` is the same as the one passed in.